# Download de arquivo Blob MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, download

Eu preciso fazer um download de um arquivo `.xls` que está em um banco MySQL, mas preciso salvar ele com o nome original.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

O upload consigo consigo fazer tranquilo. Preciso fazer o download.

```
include_once 'db.php';
$download = mysql_query("SELECT formResolucao FROM tbconfiguracoes");
$nome = mysql_result($download, 0, "nome");
$tipo = mysql_result($download, 0, "tipo");
$conteudo = mysql_result($download, 0, "conteudo");

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Type: filesize($conteudo)');
header('Content-Type: $tipo');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nome");
```

Comment: O problema é que o download não acontece?

Comment: Até baixa, mas vem corrompido.

Comment: Remova essa linha:  `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` deve estar jogando algum html no arquivo baixado.

Comment: Valeu consegui. Alterei o que falou e modifiquei algumas coisas aqui. Vou inclui o codigo aqui.

include_once 'db.php';
  $download = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbanexos where seqAnexo = 20");
  $nome = mysql_result($download, 0, "nomeAnexo");
  $tipo = mysql_result($download, 0, "tipoAnexo");
  $conteudo = mysql_result($download, 0, "arqAnexo");
 //header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Type: filesize($conteudo)');
 header('Content-Type: $tipo');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nome");
  
 return ($conteudo);

Comment: Na verdade baixou mas veio zerado.
Ele trouxe o nome correto e tal, mas vem com 0 bytes.

Comment: Depois de cabeçalho, de um echo em `$conteudo`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo, faltava o echo mesmo.

Comment: @RodrigoMotaSousa Não quer postar a solução completa como resposta? Pode ajudar futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 1):

o arquivo php tem que ficar assim:

```
include_once 'db.php';
$download = mysql_query("SELECT formResolucao FROM tbconfiguracoes");
$nome = mysql_result($download, 0, "nome");
$tipo = mysql_result($download, 0, "tipo");
$conteudo = mysql_result($download, 0, "conteudo");

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");

header("Content-Disposition: filename=".$nome.".xls");

header("Pragma: no-cache");



echo $conteudo;
```